# How to split a string into list of combinations

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

Given a string like `/root/2/1/2`, how do we construct the following list:

```
['/root/2/1/2', 'root/2/1', 'root/2', '/root']
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple implementation is to split once from the right side on `/` character iteratively until there is nothing left.

```py
left = '/root/2/1/2'
lst = []
while left:
    lst.append(left)
    left, right = left.rsplit('/', 1)

print(lst)   # ['/root/2/1/2', '/root/2/1', '/root/2', '/root']
```

Using the walrus operator, we can also write it in a single line (much less readable than the while loop though):

```py
left = '/root/2/1/2'
lst = [left, *(left for _ in range(left.count('/')) if (left:=left.rsplit('/', 1)[0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) almost does what you need:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/root/2/1/2')
print(list(str(p) for p in path.parents))
#  ['/root/2/1', '/root/2', '/root', '/']
```